# Fixing number of lines in react native for android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, listview, react-native

i need to make a list of text and title and fix for each the number of line = 2 --> so the total number of lines = 4. I did it  and it's working fine in iOS simulator. The problem now is that i only get two lines as total not 4  in android (emulator and real device). 
Here is the code i used :

```
 _renderItem(item) {
        return (    
<View>
      <Text numberOfLines={2}
            style={styles.name}>{item.name.toUpperCase()}</Text>

      <Text numberOfLines={2}
            style={styles.definition}>{item.definition}</Text>
    </View>
);}
```

and

```
render() {
        return (
                <ListView
                    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                    renderRow={this._renderItem.bind(this)}
                    enableEmptySections={true}
                    style={styles.listView}/>
        )
    }
```

I'm thinking the android listView has a fixed number of lines and can not be changed based on numberOfLines .. Any suggestion 
After making the text static and fixing the height :

```
 _renderItem(item) {
        return (
            <View style={styles.listItem}>

                        <Text numberOfLines={2} style={{ fontSize: 14, lineHeight: 15 }}>
                            &gt;"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                        </Text>

                        <Text
                            numberOfLines={2}
                            style={{ fontSize: 14, color: 'red', lineHeight: 15 }}>
                            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                        </Text>

            </View>
        );
    }
```

pictures i got after fixing height and lineHeight [image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the better way for having fixed number of lines, is to use `height` style. Add  `height` style to `Text`s parrent. The `numberOfLines` is the maximum number of lines not minimum number of lines.

**Update:**

```
_renderItem(item) {
return (
  <View style={{ height: 60 }}>
    <Text numberOfLines={2} style={{ fontSize: 14, lineHeight: 15 }}>
      &gt;"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
    </Text>

    <Text
      numberOfLines={2}
      style={{ fontSize: 14, color: 'red', lineHeight: 15 }}>
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
    </Text>
  </View>
);
```

}

Comment: hey, thank you but i tried your suggestion and it's still the same problem .. please see the update as i added pictures for both platforms

Comment: Why android version not showing red texts? I think some other thing is wrong.

Comment: hey, i made the text static .. and changed the images in the question .. please take a look

Comment: Add `height` to parent `View` and `lineHeight` to `Text`. I have updated the answer and test it on android.

Comment: still not working :( please the pictures in the question

Comment: Maybe it's about the `listItem` & `listView`. I added the example to the *expo* , and test it on android device. There isn't any problem. https://snack.expo.io/ByFIRUyJW

Comment: Increase `height` in the `listItem`, is it change?